# Decode Base 64 string to bitmap Failed

Tags: android, bitmap, base64

I am in middle of a project .I want to upload an image from my app to server.I encoded the image from imageview and upload to server as Base64 string and decoded it back to display in imageview.But I face issue with decoding Base64 string back into bitmap.I am getting

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64
```

The code I used for encoding and decoding is given below:

For encoding:

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            System.out.println("PicturePath:"+picturePath);
                       imgImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

            Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
            System.out.println("15102015 bitmap:" + bitmapOrg.toString());
            ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bao);
            byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();

            ba1= Base64.encode(ba, Base64.DEFAULT).toString();
```

For decoding:

```
byte [] encodeByte=Base64.decode(model.getmImage().toString(), Base64.DEFAULT);

            System.out.println("15102015 encodeByte:" + encodeByte.toString());
            Bitmap bitmap;
            try{

                 bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
                imgImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("15102015 Exception e:" + e.toString());

            }
```

where model.getmImage().toString() has the Base64 string value.

Please help me as I am behind this isssue for past few days.I will definitely verify your answer .

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Can you add your Base64 encoded string...!

Comment: @ArsalImam thisis the encoded string: [B@29cec3f3

Comment: This is not a valid encoded string of an image thats why it throws bad Base64 exception

Comment: What is the value of `model.getmImage()`? Isn't that a string?

Comment: Check if it is compressed or not?

Comment: @Nizam Yes it is ..The value of the string is  [B@29cec3f3

Comment: @ArsalImam Is there any alternative way to upload an image to server.i mean not the patch actuall image i want to sent.

Comment: Yes, you can use multi-part system to upload image on server which is mostly used...!

Comment: If you want to use it, I will send you the piece of code that I am using for my application